# Publish live dashboard to own web-site using Tableau

Tags: cloudera, tableau-api

I am currently using Tableau Desktop. The data I'm using is connected to a Cloudera hadoop server. I was able to create a dashboard.
My question: is it possible to show that dashboard live at my own web-site (e.g., www.myblog.com) for others to see? if that is only possible with other Tableau products, how does it work? do I just buy the product or do I buy a server from Tableau? Can you please tell me how I can post a live dashboard on my own web-site for everyone to see.

Thank you,

Amr

Answer (score 2):

You will need to have some sort of Tableau Server involved, either one you purchase and run yourself or Tableau Online. If it's the latter, you will likely not be connecting live, but will be refreshing the data periodically. If you run Tableau Server yourself, you'll set it up as externally facing. There's a video on the Tableau website where a Tableau customer has done this. http://www.tableau.com/learn/webinars/increase-customer-engagement-interactive-analytics

That can give you an idea of how it works. Depending on how technically savvy you are, you can set it up yourself or hire someone to do it for you.